# Not able to use 'super' with function defined on protoype object in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, super

I have class `A` which is parent of class `B`

```
class A {
    constructor(a){
        this.a=a;
    }

    par(){
        console.log("para");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(a) {
        super(a)
        this.a = "child";
    }

    par() {
        super.par();
        console.log("child");
    }
}
```

When I use this code, it works fine.

But when I explicitly define the `par` function on `B` using this code:

```
B.prototype.par = function() {
    super.par();
}
```

I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

Whether we create a function in class definition or in prototype object of function('class'), it should be the same thing.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No, you can't use `super` in a `function`. Just call `A.prototype.par`.

Answer (score 1):

'super' is simply a syntactic sugar introduced in ES2015 along with class syntax.
It can only be used within functions of 'class' (constructor and methods) that extends another class.

```
class A {
  constructor(){}
  par(){ console.log('para') }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
function A(){}
A.prototype.par = function(){console.log('para')}

var B = (function(parent){
  var _super = parent;
  function B(){
    _super.call(this); // calls parent's constructor
  }

  B.prototype = Object.create(_super.prototype); // Inherits parent's methods.

  B.prototype.par = function(){ // override parent's par.
    _super.prototype.par.call(this); // child still has access to parent's par method thanks to closure :)
    console.log('child');
  }

  return B;
})(A);

var b = new B();
b.par()
```

You cannot do:

```
function(){
  super // super is not defined...
}
```

Comment: i have doubt in this line  'B.prototype = new _super();'..what is it trying to do?
because 'b.__proto__' will be equal to B.prototype

Comment: @Bergi You're right. It should be Object.create(A.prototype). I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
B.prototype.par = function(){ 
      Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).par.call(this);
}

var b = new B();
b.par()
```

Explanation:
Calling `b.par()` leads to `this` pointing to b inside the function body. Therefore `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)` is `b`'s prototype (that is: class `B`) and `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))` is class `A`. We retrieve function `par` from A and call it with it's `this`-reference pointing to `b`.